# Create two elements for a single `ngFor` iteration?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-template

I am looping on a collection of models and want to show one element per model. However, for CSS reasons, I must add another element when I reach the forth model (I need to add a Bootstrap `clearfix` element for the layout to look good).

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <ol class="row">
        <li *ngFor="#card of deck; #i = index" class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>{{ card.name }}</h3>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

How do I say if `(i + 1) % 4 === 0`, then add this `li` plus another `<li class="clearfix"></li>`?

Comment: Does it work if instead adding a new <li> you add the class to the <li> you already have? `<li ... [class.clearfix]="(i + 1) % 4 === 0">`, if it doesn't work you can use the <template> form instead.

Comment: No that doesn't work as I need both the "normal" `li` and the `clearfix` `li`, it can't be the same. But you are right, I continued my research and I think using the template form is the solution. You can either post it as an answer, or I'll post it when I get something that works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This can be done with the `<ng-container>` helper element

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <ol class="row">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let card of deck" let-i="index"> 
          <li class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>{{ card.name }}</h3>
          </li>
          <li *ngIf="(i + 1) % 4 === 0" class="clearfix"></li>
        </ng-container>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

---

An alternative approach (used before `<ng-container>` became available)

This can be done with the long `ngFor` form with an explicit `<template>` tag like

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <ol class="row">
        <template ngFor let-card [ngForOf]="deck" let-i="index"> 
          <li class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>{{ card.name }}</h3>
          </li>
          <li *ngIf="(i + 1) % 4 === 0" class="clearfix"></li>
        </template>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rJ44n3?p=preview)

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html