# What is the difference between ngFor and *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot find a good description of the differences anywhere. Same with `*ngIf` and `ngIf`

An example of `*ngFor`

```
<li *ngFor="let video of page" ...>
  <img src="api/Videos/{{video.id}}/thumbnail">
</li>
```

and an example of `ngFor`

```
<template ngFor let-labelid [ngForOf]="labelLookup | keyValueFilter" >
  <label  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': labelLookup[labelid].color}">
    <input (click)="changeLabel(labelid)" type="radio" name="labelSelector" value="{{ labelid }}" [checked]="labelid == 1">
  </label>
</template>
```

Comment: `*ngFor` is shorthand of `ngFor` with `template`, you can find the same on angular docs & teropa blog [here](https://teropa.info/blog/2016/03/06/writing-an-angular-2-template-directive.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that `*ngFor` is converted to `<template ngFor [ngForOf]="..."` internally.

They are equivalent but the former is more convenient to write.

The explicit version (`<template ngFor ...>`) allows to apply the directive to multiple elements at once while the implicit version (shorthand) only wraps the element where it is applied to with the `<template>` tag.

With Angular 2.0.0 final the `<ng-container>` element was added that allows to use the shorthand syntax on an element that behaves like the `<template>` element (is not added to the DOM).

See also

- [*ngIf and *ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error/34659638#34659638)
- [Create two elements for a single `ngFor` iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376006/create-two-elements-for-a-single-ngfor-iteration/36376185#36376185)