# Add sibling logic in ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a table in angular template, the rows of which are generated by iteration over an object using **ngFor** directive.Example code:

```html
<table *ngIf="results.length > 0" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
      <th class="col-md-3">Code</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Type</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Value(s)</th>
      <th class="col-md-2"><b class="invisible">.</b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of results">
      <td class="col-md-1">{{r.id}}</td>
      <td class="col-md-3">{{r.code}}</td>
      <td class="col-md-2">{{r.type}}</td>
      <td class="col-md-4">{{r.values}}</td>
      <td class="col-md-2">
        <button (click)="add(r.id)">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden"> // <----- The following lines needs to repeat for all iterations
      <td colspan="5">
        // Some other code
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My purpose is to get a complete row just below each row that gets generated by **ngFor**, so that on click of button on each row, I can show the respective row just below the row that contains the button.

Is this possible to achieve in a simple way?

Comment: I havent tested it but i think you can achieve the desired result using a `<ng-container>` as explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376006/create-two-elements-for-a-single-ngfor-iteration#36376185

Comment: @FabioG Ok that works. Thank You. ( Hell !! I'm new to Angular ;-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use ng-container like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let r of results">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Accepting the answer, but I feel, a bit of explanation would have made this answer more useful.

Comment: you can read about structural-directives at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this and the table should still render fine:

```
<table *ngIf="results.length > 0" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div *ngFor="let r of results">
      <tr>
        ...
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        ...
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or rather the schematically correct version provided in the other answer.

Comment: Well it works, but I'm getting some styling problems with this approach. So, I would go with @FabioG's suggestion and use `<ng-container>`